# Golang OpenSSL bad iv size

Tags: go, openssl

I'm trying to create the following:

```
cipher, err := openssl.GetCipherByName("aes-128-ecb")
decryptionTool, err := openssl.NewDecryptionCipherCtx(cipher, nil, byteKey, iv)
```

The byteKey and iv are both 16 bytes long.

When I build my code, I get the following error:

```
panic: bad IV size (16 bytes instead of 0)
```

I read the documentation, and checked the source code, but I still can't find a way to add the IV without getting an error. I am using spacemonkeygo's OpenSSL.

Does anyone know what's wrong?
And thanks in advance!

EDIT: I added the cipher type above, and a bit more details about biteKey and iv

EDIT 2: ECB has no IV! I totally forgot about that. Well I guess that solves it.

Comment: It depends on the content of parameters `chiper`, `byteKey`, `iv`. Without detail information, its hard to find what was wrong.

Comment: My guess is that your cipher has been defined to have a zero length IV. What cipher are you using?

Comment: I'm using aes-128-ecb. I added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

I used ECB the first time, and I wanted to change it to CBC. I forgot to change it to aes-cbc and so I got an error when I tried adding an IV.